# How can I interrupt getCurrentLocation method (Codename One Location Manager)?

Tags: geolocation, codenameone

My app features a map and when the user long presses on it, I need the current phone location to appear on the map. As @Chen [advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512619/proper-way-of-using-locationmanager-in-codename-one) it looks like getCurrentLocation() is the proper method to use in my case. Please note that I don't want to use a LocationListener because I want the user to have control on when they want to update their location.

Moreover I chose this manual location update because @Shai-Almog [discouraged location polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35118474/codename-one-retrieving-location-at-regular-time-intervals). So after reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35122294/codename-one-gps-provider-and-current-location) I first set the timeout to 20 s as written below to get the current phone location :

```
                Dialog ip = new InfiniteProgress().showInifiniteBlocking();
                Location currentLocation = locationManager.getCurrentLocationSync(
                        ParametresGeneraux.LOCATION_TIMEOUT_MILLI);
                // We try to get something
                if (currentLocation == null) {
                    currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation();
                }
                ip.dispose();
```

But it was not sufficient and the last known location was "always" provided (I did not count maybe 5 times in a row) although the little location icon appeared in the toolbar. So I set it to 40 s but the actual current location did not come either after this twice as big amount of time (only the last known location which is > 2km away was provided).

However if I start Google Maps on Android (KitKat), the location is instantaneously  accurate. And then if I go back to my app and press the map the current location is found. Actually I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752726/retrieving-geo-location-in-my-app-is-far-less-accurate-than-what-google-maps-app) dealing with a  difference in accuracy between Google Maps  and Android API but it was pertaining to Shangai / China, not the EU (France).

Consequently my question is twofold :

1. first how can there be such a huge difference on the same device between Google Maps and Codename One ?
2. then if I don't set a timeout to `getCurrentLocation()` how can I interrupt the location searching when the user is fed up waiting ?

Any help appreciated,

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instant location will work if the Google Maps location services is turned on. If you enabled or disabled one of the `android.playService` build hints you must also enable `android.playService.location=true` to get the fast location service used by maps.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a ton @Shai!Adding android.playService.location=true to the build hints makes the current location appear faster ([more details on CN1 blog](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/a-thank-you-an-important-update-on-android-builds.html)). So far it is still not accurate but Google Maps does not work either so I cannot make a comparison. By the way did you see my other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41695584/buttons-in-codename-one-form-inactive-on-android-actual-device-but-work-under-si)?

Comment: I missed that question, did you forget to tag it initially?

Comment: No I didn't forget, was just surprised because you always answer quickly. Anyway thanks for having replied!

Comment: I think SO changed the behavior of the default tag view that I used from active "new" to "active" and that might have pushed this answer down. Then they reverted it back because it's a stupid default but by then I already missed the question.